# Default PHP function is interpreted as a library function from Composer in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class like this:

```
namespace my\namespace;

use this\object;

include("a/b/c/vendor/autoload.php");

class TestClass
{
    public function index()
    {
    $url = "www.myweb.com";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
 //   ... do more things
    }
}
```

In symphony.

This used to work until yesterday, now PHP thinks that `curl_init` is a different function, I get this error:

```
Attempted to call function "curl_init" from namespace "my\namespace"
```

PHPStorms says `curl_init is missing from composer.json`.

I am using the web server included in Symfony (`php bin/console server:start`)

I am not sure what changed here. Any help would be great.

Comment: What you've done from yesterday?

Comment: Did you run it on a different machine before? This method requires that the curl-extension for php is installed. I guess it is missing from whatever machine is executing the code.

Comment: @dbrumann This is acutally the problem post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the curl extension is missing from the machine. You can ensure it's installed by adding it as a dependency to your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "ext-curl": "*",
    ...
}
```